# Blazor pass data on navigating

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, blazor, blazor-server-side

I want to exchange data between different pages (razor

I have 2 pages:
list.razor
view.razor

In view.razor, there is a form which calls a method on valid submit. This method adds an bootstrap alert to my service AlertService.

The list.razor reads all entries from the service and creates a Alert razor component for each alert.

```
@foreach (var alert in AlertService.GetAlerts())
    {
        <Alert AlertBox="alert" />
    }
```

The problem I am facing now is that once I delete the message from my service, the razor component refreshs itself and my alert is gone. But I want to display the continuously. It should be gone once the user reloads or switch the page.

I allready tried to create a copy of the alerts from my service but it does not seem to be the solution here.

```
public List<IAlert> GetAlerts()
{
    var tmp = Alerts.ToList();
    Alerts = new List<IAlert>();
    return tmp;
}
```

I added my service in the startup as:

```
services.AddSingleton<AlertService>();
```

Is there any way to solve this? What am I doing wrong here?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is this question about Blazor, the new SPA framework, or Razor Pages?

Comment: blazor server sided.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like the issue here is that you have the alerts rendering hardwired to your AlertService singleton, but the behavior you need is your view responding to the service but storing information independently.

The way you have your list reading from the service set up, it's using the list in the service as the list it's rendering, which will tie everything together since they are reference types. Any changes in the service list will naturally be reflected in the page, for better or worse. The way you have your question phrased, I am assuming that you want the alerts to appear only for list items that are added after the page loads. What you need is a mechanism to decouple the alerts in the service from what is displayed on the page. So perhaps a better approach is to use the service to do nothing more that pass the alert information along as an event. It's fairly simple to set up this way actually, and it takes setup in 4 places.

**StringEventArgs.cs**

Here was are extending the basic EventArgs class to allow passing strings around in event calls. This `StringEventArgs` type will then be used later in our `AlertService`, `View.razor` and `List.razor` classes.

```cs
public class StringEventArgs : EventArgs
{
    public string Value { get; set; }
}
```

This works just like `EventArgs` would, but it will allow setting the `Value` property and sending a string value with it. (This can also be used with any other value you want to send, even up to complex object types. Just extend `EventArgs` to suit your needs.)

**AlertService.cs**

Your service class can be very simple if you use this method, as all it's doing is acting as a message hub to pass information around.

```cs
public class AlertService
{
    public Func<object, StringEventArgs, Task> SendAlert;

    public Task OnAlertRequested(object sender, StringEventArgs e)
    {
        SendAlert?.Invoke(sender, e);
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
}
```

Pretty standard event based stuff here, just using `StringEventArgs` instead of the standard `EventArgs`.

**View.Razor**

The only thing you need to change in this file is to pass the message through your service when you have a valid form submission. You mentioned you have a method that is called on valid submit of your form, that adds the alert to the list. So the method should look something like this. Note that I show injecting the service to clarify the name.

```cs
[Inject] public AlertService Service { get; set;}

void HandleValidSubmit(string alertMessage, other params...)
{
    // code to handle other params
    Service.OnAlertRequested(this, new StringEventArgs() { Value = alertMessage});
}
```

What this has done is call the method in your service that triggers the event, using a new instance of StringEventArgs that passes the alert value in. As long as the `SendAlert` event in your service has any subscribers, the service will invoke any subscribed methods, which we will do next.

**List.Razor**

This is the last piece of functionality that you need to include and all this will start working. We'll make list of alert values that is initialized every time a new page is loaded, and populate it with alert messages as they are sent out through the service.

```cs
@implements IDisposable

@foreach (var alert in AlertList)
{
    <Alert AlertBox="alert" />
}

@code {
    
    [Inject] public AlertService Service { get; set;}

    // Always initializes to a fresh list on component start
    public List<string> AlertList { get; set; } = new List<string>();

    //This handler will be called whenever the event defined in AlertService
    //triggers, and will accept StringEventArgs which can be passed from the event caller
    //Note that this needs to be ASYNC so you can await the 'InvokeAsync' call below 
    private async Task OnAlertReceived(object sender, StringEventArgs e)
    {
        AlertList.Add(e.Value);    
        await InvokeAsync(StateHasChanged);
    }

    //Triggered when the page builds and renders
    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
        //Unsubsribe once to make sure you only have one event subscription
        //This prevents event propogation, and won't do anything unless you are 
        //already subscribed for some reason
        Service.SendAlert -= OnAlertReceived;

        //Subscribe to the event 
        Service.SendAlert += OnAlertReceived;
    }

    //IMPORTANT - add Dispose and unsubscribe on teardown
    //prevents event propogation and memory leaks.
    public void Dispose()
    {
        Service.SendAlert -= OnAlertReceived;
    }

}
```

What this does is give you a method called `OnAlertReceived` in your list to react to `SendAlert` notifications from the Service, and then uses `OnInitialized`  to register that method to trigger whenever the service calls for it. The method receives the StringEventArgs object, and adds the `Value` property to the `AlertList` list. The list of alerts is now independent of the service entirely, and lives only in the `List.razor` component, so each instance of your List component will only show alerts that were generated after it has been initialized. Lastly, the `Dispose` method makes sure the event subscription gets removed when you are done with it, so you don't have memory leaks.

This should get you moving, but one thing to point out. Because you have your service registered as a singleton, the alert will go out to all users in all separate windows they have open, as long as `List.razor` is included in whatever is in that window. If you only want it to work for individual users, you might use a scoped service instead, and make sure you are not inheriting from `OwningComponentBase`. [Further reading here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/dependency-injection?view=aspnetcore-3.1#utility-base-component-classes-to-manage-a-di-scope). I also have a demo project posted on Github [here](https://github.com/nikfp/BlazorUIEvents) if you want something you can download and poke around in.

Hope this helps!